# How can I change the distribution curve (kde) smoothing of a histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

With the following code I can visualize data with a histogram and its kernel density estimation (kde).

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/diamonds.csv')


plt.subplots(figsize=(7,6), dpi=100)
#sns.distplot( df.loc[df.species=='setosa', "sepal_length"] , color="dodgerblue", label="Setosa")
#sns.distplot( df.loc[df.species=='virginica', "sepal_length"] , color="orange", label="virginica")
#sns.distplot( df.loc[df.species=='versicolor', "sepal_length"] , color="deeppink", label="versicolor")

sns.histplot(df.loc[df.cut=='Good', 'depth'], bins= 100, color="blue", label="pcts", kde = True)

plt.title('Iris Histogram')
plt.legend();
```

The resulting graph output is as follows:

[image]

How can I adjust the kernel smoothing line graph so that the curve does not run so smoothly but follows more the shape of the histogram?

The result should be something more like the red curve in this plot:
[image]

Or am I just mixing things up and the curve I am looking for corresponds to a probability density function (pdf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `sns.kdeplot()` keywords to `sns.histplot` as a dictionary. To change the smoothness of the KDE plot, you want to play with the `bw_adjust` parameter.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

random_data = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
sns.histplot(random_data, bins=100, kde = True, kde_kws={"bw_adjust":0.25}, ax=ax[0])
sns.histplot(random_data, bins=100, kde = True, kde_kws={"bw_adjust":5}, ax=ax[1])
```

[image]

Comment: @ Anonymous this works perfectly. Thank you. I missread the documentation and tried the bw_adjust method directly without "kde_kws = ...."  Is it also possible to use this methon on kdeplot instead of histplot?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, `bw_adjust` is a parameter of `kdeplot`, so you pass it directly: `sns.kdeplot(..., bw_adjust=0.5)`.

Comment: @ Anonymous That works. There is the core of mymisunderstanding: I mixed up the two plot possiblities and their different parameter spelling. thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `kde_kws` parameter you can specify `bw_adjust` which according to the [kdeplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot) adjusts the bandwidth value returned by the method set in 'bw_method'.
Try setting it to e.g. `0.1` by appending `kde_kws={'bw_adjust':0.1}` such that your code becomes:
`sns.histplot(df.loc[df.cut=='Good', 'depth'], bins= 100, color="blue", label="pcts", kde = True, kde_kws={'bw_adjust':0.1})`

If that's not enough you probably have to tweak `bw_method`.

Comment: @ stroblme: this works perfectly. Thank you. I missread the documentation and tried the bw_adjust method directly without "kde_kws = ...."